# Record video from camera with specific frame rate and extract frames in bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, android-camera

I need to record a video with a given frame-rate (between 20 and 30) for 20 seconds and specific resolution while the flashlight is on, and after that extract the frames in bitmap format to an array but I don’t know how do that, can you help me how achieve this or tell me some of the good libraries which can handle this for me?

I want to do some processing on these bitmaps then, so in order to increase performance and speed if it is possible to process the frames in real time instead of first recording and then processing let me know how it will be done.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use Camera2 API to record video and look into fmpeg for video manipulation

Comment: Can I set specific frame rate and resolution for recording in Camera2? and what about API<21? @VeneetReddy

Comment: Yes. Pre 21 you have to handle using Camera API.